# Turn a string into a regexp that matches the plain string, in DrScheme

Tags: regex, string

I want to split a string based on a non-regular expression. My input is a plain string. So, for example, given the input `"hello.*there"` and `".*"`, I want the result ("hello" "there").

Doing this obv doesn't work:

```
(regexp-split (regexp sep) str))
```

since it will try to match the regular expression `.*`. How do I escape `sep` to nullify any regexp-like patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claudiu, many of the questions you have asked about PLT-Scheme are answered in the documentation. Not to say it's wrong to ask questions, sometimes you'll get a more in-depth answer here.

There are many documents in the set of documentation that comes with PLT-Scheme. There are 2 pieces of documentation you want to be familiar with:

1. The PLT Scheme Guide. http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide/index.html
2. The PLT Scheme Reference: http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/index.html

Both are installed locally when you install PLT-Scheme (formerly called DrScheme).

The Guide is intended for those new to Scheme or PLT-Scheme. The Reference is more in depth.

Eli pointed to the link in the Reference documentation. The regexp-quote function is also mentioned is the much shorter and more readable Guide, here http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide/regexp-intro.html along with mention of quoting special characters using \, as well as a link to the Reference documentation.

Comment: thanks! my main problem is that i wasn't able to find a good link to the documentation by google searching, or the docs i found were for certain modules which i didn't know how to import. these are a good place to start though

Answer (score 3):

[regexp-quote](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#(def._((lib._racket/private/base..rkt)._regexp-quote)))